# Avoiding jQuery Event for Specific Callers

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-datepicker

On our page we have logic that catches any changes on Input/Select/TextArea controls on `input`/`change`. But one specific case we need to exclude (ignore) is this event getting called by Bootstrap DatePicker initialization in the beginning.

It turns out that calling the startup Bootstrap DatePicker initialization below also triggers the `change` event on the associated textfield control. This is what gets triggered, and should be blocked specifically for datepicker initialization:

```js
$(document).on("change", "input", function () {
  alert("change!");
});

$('#datepicker').datepicker({
  startDate: "01/01/2010",
  endDate: "01/01/2050",                      
  orientation: "bottom auto",
  todayHighlight: true,
  autoclose: true
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.6.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css">

<input type="text" id="datepicker">
```

The question is how to not activate the On Change event for the `.datepicker()` caller.

Any subsequent (post-page-startup, i.e. non-`.datepicker()`) keystrokes on the Date text fields **should** trigger this Change event.

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ja50pzuc/

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How to **not** activate the On Change event for the `.datepicker()` caller. It needs to do whatever it does for its own `change`, but avoid going into this custom block.

Answer (score 2):

Use a global variable to track how many times the change handler is called, and ignore the first call.

```
var clicked = false;

$(document).on("change", "input", function () {
  if ( clicked ) {
    // Do your normal processing here
  } else {
    // Ignore this click (but not subsequent ones)
    clicked = true;
  }
});
```

Another option would be to set up a dummy event handler, and upon the first "click" it would swap itself out for the real event handler:

```
$(document).on("change", "input", function () {
  // Remove this dummy event handlers and add the "real" one:
  $(this).off("change", "input").on("change", "input", function() {
    // This is the real event handler, which gets called starting with the 2nd change/input
    // Do the handling stuff here
    // ...
  });
});
```

Comment: Our problem is we have **multiple** Date fields that get initialized, not just 1. We need to skip all of that initialization, so we won't be getting the 2nd entry. We will be getting the 10th or 11th entry (that's how many Date fields we have on the page).

Comment: @geneb.Why not just initialize all the DatePicker objects before adding the event handlers?

Comment: You mean make sure that the handler is added **after** `.datepicker()` in the JS execution?

Comment: @geneb.Yes, exactly

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
$("input,select,textarea").not("#datepicker input[type=text]")
```

Comment: No, that won't work. As I said, I  **want* that field to pick up later changes. I just don't want it to pick up the initial .datepicker initialization caller.